Excel: Pivoting/Transforming monthyly expense data
I have an excel workbook that has a sheet for every month of the year.
each sheet is used to capture some basic general ledger information for that month.
I have managed to create a power query to pull all data for each sheet and combine such that they look like this:





NAME
SUPPLIES
UTILITIES
INSURANCE
ADVERTISEMENT
PAYROLL
MONTH




Entity 1
100
100
100
100

JAN


Entity 2
200
200
200


JAN


Entity 3


50

400
JAN


Entity 1
100
100
100
100

FEB


Entity 2
200
200
200


FEB


Entity 3


50

400
FEB




I would like to use this query now in a new tab but such what the columns are the months, rows are the the columns except 'Name', and values of the sell are summed accordingly, so should end up with something like this:

I have tried to do this by using a pivot table/report, but unsuccessfully.  instead of listing the selected columns as individual rows, it is also  summing them across..so that i end up with 1 row..but multiple column groupings of 'jan' and feb'.  similar to this:

Anyone know if this can be done with a pivot?  or do i need to do the pivoting, grouping and aggregation with powerquery much like we would in SQL? if so are there examples of doing this w/ power query?
thanks much

Should be relatively easy using Power Query --> Unpivot and then Pivot

Unpivot? what on earth is that?

Its the opposite of pivoting, like you are transposing the whole structure into vertically

Please don't upload images of code/data/errors.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

@taller does that work with excel cut and paste?

Yes, just try it.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"NAME", "MONTH"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"NAME"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[MONTH]), "MONTH", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Attribute", "Categories"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"





Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.



this looks promising.  one question - as im very new to Power Query..i already have a query that exists with the data as i described.  instead of source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook, how can i reference that query instead?

@mike01010 for Excel.CurretWorkbook() when you see it in PQ window, you need to filter the tables you need, what is it showing presently?

i already fetched and combined the data into a query using pwoer query..is what im trying to say.  or do i now have to add that data to a sheet only to be able to use your solution?  why cant i use  source = {already existing query}

@mike01010 ok so you have already got the data in the PQ editor right? Now have you performed the output which you are asking for?

ok..i figure out that i can right click my query and select 'reference'.  maybe thats how

@mike01010 you dont have to do anything here, just delete the query what you have and just open a new blank query and paste the m-code that i have posted in advanced editor you will only need to change the name in example it is table 1 change it with the one you have

worked! thanks a million!

the reason i needed my intermediary query is i have 12 tabs representing months of the year. i use another combined query to pull all the data into one.  i then use that as the source to your suggested query.

Ah okay understood. Hmm, for that, the same solution should work, but you will need some changes, which means you need to map the previous steps so the m-code can work, bt the logic remains same here, first hold down the CTRL key and select the name and month column right click unpivot other. Now select the month column, goto transform tab, click on pivot and change the aggregation type to SUM. ensuring to select values ok.

Also for reference, it will be helpful for you and everyone of us, can use this Markdown_Table_Generator its very easy to use, just you need to copy the table from your worksheet and paste in the web, it automatically creates the table generation.
